# Программа не видит строку "Ctrl+Break"

Tags: python

Код должен отлавливать строку 'ctrl+break', выводить 'bye-bye' и завершать программу, но почему то пропускает мимо и выводит 'ok'.

```
import sys


class PasswordError(Exception):
    pass


class LengthError(PasswordError):
    pass


class LetterError(PasswordError):
    pass


class DigitError(PasswordError):
    pass


class SequenceError(PasswordError):
    pass


def check_password():
    start = 0
    end = 3
    const_en = ['qwertyuiop', 'asdfghjkl', 'zxcvbnm']
    const_ru = ['йцукенгшщзхъ', 'фывапролджэё', 'ячсмитьбю']
    const_zn = ".,|\}]{[()!@#$%^&*№;:?~`+=_-" + '"'
    for line in sys.stdin:
        try:
            if line == 'Ctrl+Break':
                print('Bye-Bye')
                return
            if len(line) < 9:
                raise LengthError()
            for i in range(len(const_zn)):
                if const_zn[i] in line:
                    line = line.replace(const_zn[i], '')
            if line.isalpha():
                raise DigitError()
            if line.isupper() or line.islower() or line.isdigit():
                raise LetterError()
            for i in range(len(line) - 2):
                for j in range(3):
                    if line[start:end].lower() in const_en[j] or line[start:end].lower() in const_ru[j]:
                        raise SequenceError()
                start += 1
                end += 1
            print('ok')
            return
        except LengthError:
            print('LengthError')
        except DigitError:
            print('DigitError')
        except LetterError:
            print('LetterError')
        except SequenceError:
            print('SequenceError')
    print('Bye-Bye')


check_password()
```

Comment: Если вам надо проверить, что есть вхождение в строку набор символов "Ctrl+break". Надо проверить не  line == "Ctrl+break", а "Ctrl+break" in line. Т.е. если будет вхождение, то до свидание.
Или через line.find("Ctrl+break")  .... т.е. через метод для строки

Comment: В условии как написано - должен отлавливать такую строку, или завершаться при нажатии (клавиш) Ctrl + Break?

Comment: @Volk спасибо, получилось

Comment: @weben. Давайте я оформлю это в виде ответа. А вы закроете вопрос как раз и пометите ответ. Будет здорово! :) в целом, рад, что сработало.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы пытаетесь найти строку равную "Ctrl+break". В этом ошибка. В строке может быть куча другого текста, который совершенно не причем.
Вам надо проверять на то, чтобы в строке было стоп-значение "Ctrl+break".  И это будет ключом к задаче. Т.е. вместо проверки условия:

```
line == "Ctrl+break"
```

Надо поставить:

```
"Ctrl+break" in line
```

Соответственно, если у вфшеуказанной строчки значение True (если есть Ctrl+break), то система говорит "bye-bye", иначе идет дальше и пишет "ok"
Есть ещё вариант решения вашей задачи через метод поиска подстроки в строке:

```
if line.find("Ctrl+break") == -1:
    print('ok')
```

Где line - это строка, в которой вы совершаете поиск, а "Ctrl+break" - искомая величина. Метод find возвращает значение -1 если искомой подстроки нет в строке line.

Comment: Только вы не написали, как должна выглядеть проверка условия через `line.find` (с чем должно быть сравнение). Но в любом случае лучше проверять через `in`, если конкретная позиция, где найдена подстрока, не важна.

Comment: Согласен с вашим комментарием. Я вот и думал расписывать или нет :) Спасибо!

Comment: Так дополните свой ответ. Потому что если кто-то напишет просто if line.find ... то это не сработает правильным образом.

Comment: Вот теперь хорошо